When writing the word "nginx", when should it be majuscule and when should it be minuscule?
When I browse F5, "nginx" is consistently majuscule as "NGINX":

When browsing nginx.org, both "NGINX" and "nginx" are used:

When is it appropriate to use majuscule "NGINX" or minuscule "nginx"?

If you write things regarding the BSD-licenses software (including current & future distributors & forks), disregard what the current commercial "owner" does. Servers (or any system daemons, really) are traditionally spelt all-ASCII-lowercase for interoperability and principle of least surprise.
If you write things regarding the commercial offerings, match their spelling and clarify the entity selling it.
